# JQ: What is the shorter syntax to get the value

Tags: json, jq

I used the following long command to get a JSON value `7.3.9-win-x64.msi` that I included below.

```bash
$ cat json.txt  | jq -r '.[] | .[] | .[] | .[].management | .[0].microsoft | .shell.associated.scripting.component.windows.powershell'
```

For JSON code it is:

```json
{
  "PowerShell": {
    "is a task": {
      "automation": [
        {
          "and": "configuration",
          "management": [
            {
              "program": "from",
              "microsoft": {
                "consisting of": "a command-line",
                "shell": {
                  "and": "the",
                  "associated": {
                    "scripting": {
                      "language.": "initially a windows",
                      "component": {
                        "only": "known as",
                        "windows": {
                          "powershell": "7.3.9-win-x64.msi",
                          "it was made": "open-source"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "the former": "is built on the .NET Framework",
          "the latter on": ".NET (previously .NET Core)."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I failed when I tried to apply several methods that I got from several articles on the internet to get the same value in a shorter way. So is there a more shortest command to do it?.

Comment: *"I tried to apply several methods"*. Much better to include the 2-3 failed methods (the ones you thought were going to work) so readers can help improve your understanding of how `jq` works.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the full path must be specified along the lines of your attempt, you could slightly shorten it by skipping the explicit pipes:

```
.[][][][].management[0].microsoft.shell.associated.scripting.component.windows.powershell
```

Answer (score 1):

If you’re willing to take the risk, you could go with s.t. like:

```
.. | objects | .powershell // empty
```

Or if you know s.t. distinctive about the string of interest, e.g. that it ends with ".msi":

```
.. | strings | select(endswith(".msi"))
```

Comment: I've tried your 2 commands above but they always get errors. Can you provide full syntax of command for both ?. So I can learn with.

Comment: With your input in input.json, I checked both using the template: `jq 'LINE' input.json`